# How to circumvent a parent classes implementations of equals, toString, clone overriden object methods in the grandchild class

Tags: java

Does an arbitrary parent classes overriden `equal`, `clone`, `toString` methods get called when I invoke these methods on the subclass object, or does my subclass use the Object classes implementations? If the parent classes overriden versions get invoked instead of the object class's is there a way around this and have subclass object call the Object's methods?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could write a simple class and easily test this out.

Comment: 100% agreed. Give it a shot and see what happens.

Comment: Actually I'm looking for a way around this? I want the object's methods called for a subclass who's parent class overrides the objects methods. Wrongly questioned....

Comment: First off, the "superclass" is the one being overridden.  The overriding class is the "subclass".

Comment: Then override the child method and don't call `super.equals()`? Perhaps you should review the fundamentals of OOP.

Comment: Look at the definition of `super`.

Comment: This is a core OO inheritance concept: The child's method is always called when it overrides a superclass method, no matter what the type of the variable referencing the instance.

Comment: Qix and Hot Licks, how can I use the default object's equals method (that guarantees uniqueness) as well as the object's clone method as terribly broken as it may be, on a subclass a few hierarchies down the chain with parents that have their own implementations of these methods. lets not jump the gun and mark this question nonsensical.

Comment: The default object's `equal` method does NOT guarantee uniqueness, only the uniqueness of the objects' *references*.

Comment: what ever the case may be, I don't want the parents implementations to get in the way of my grandchilds class...

Comment: @TazMan Inherited behavior is one of the cornerstones of OO programming. Are you sure there really should be a parent-child relationship? What you're proposing breaks the `equals()` contract, I'm pretty sure.

Comment: Unfortuantely it's code that I have not written and I must use this api.. I need to access the equals and clone method of the object class..

Comment: @TazMan Is it that hard to look up the implementations yourself then?

Answer (score -1):

It would use the overridden methods of the superclass.

Comment: This answers half of the un-researched and easily answerable question.

Comment: Only answering the part I know.